# How to Display Posts From Category Within a Custom Taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, custom-taxonomy, terms

I am trying to listing posts from a single category of my custom taxonomy.

I have created a custom post type called "news" and a custom taxonomy called "instituteName".

I then created a number of categories using the "instituteName" taxonomy.

I would now like to display the posts from only a single category. e.g. i have created a category "businessSchool" underneath "instituteName" taxonomy. Now I want to display the four latest post the "businessSchool" category only.

[image: screenshot]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using custom WP_Query:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'=>'news',
    'posts_per_page'=>4,
    'tax_query'=>array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'=>'instituteName',
            'field'=>'slug',
            'terms'=>'businessschool'  // change to real slug
        )
     )
) );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    // display post
}
```

PS. This link would be helpful, I guess: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks for the help, But its not working...:( I have tried "<?php 
  query_posts( array('post_type' => 'news', 'taxonomy'=>'InstituteName', 'category_name' => 'businessSchool', 'showposts' => 4 ) );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>"...

Comment: But not working, If i don't add category name, then its working but display all the post underneath "InstituteName" taxonomy.

Comment: You shouldn't use 'category_name' - your custom taxonomy IS NOT category. Take a look at my code - it uses `tax_query` and you should use it... The only thing you have to look out is replacing `businessschool` with correct term slug.

Comment: Thanks, Tried the same code, but not working, Even not displaying single post..:(

Comment: Are you sure that you modify it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

@Krzysiek answer above didn't work because have_posts is a method not a property. It should be have_posts() not have_posts. Here's the corrected code:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'=>'news',
    'posts_per_page'=>4,
    'tax_query'=>array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'=>'instituteName',
            'field'=>'slug',
            'terms'=>'businessschool'  // change to real slug
        )
     )
) );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    // display post
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'product_cat' => 'meditations-intensives', 
    'order' => 'DESC' );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; 
  endwhile;?>
```